# optional ofstream parameter in C++

Tags: c++, ofstream, optional-arguments

How can I make an ofstream argument optional?

```
bool LookingFor(std::string &mi_name, ofstream &my_file = std::cout)
{
    my_file << xxx;
.......

}
```

the compiling error with the above method signature is:

'std::ofstream& my_file' has type 'std::ostream {aka std::basic_ostream}'

I'm using mingw32.

I want this function to write to console when there is no a second parameter.
I tried myriad things, but nothing works.
I do not mind if I have to check the code to see if it is open, for instance:

```
if(my_file.isopen())
    my_file << xxx;
else
    cout << xxx;
```

any good idea?

Answer (score 4):

Just use `ostream`:

```
bool LookingFor(std::string &mi_name, std::ostream &out = std::cout) {
    out << xxx;
}
```

This will work with any stream type, not only `fstream`, but also `cout`. And other stream types, like `ostringstream`.